# Jhipster - Traefik - Gateway ( http://localhost/gateway/#/ ) - POST http://localhost/auth/logout 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jhipster

I am using jhipster 4.10.2 with TraefiK as L.B. I am able to access and login into gateway (http://localhost/gateway/#/).

I get the following error when I try to log out.

> POST http://localhost/auth/logout 404 (Not Found)
>   {_body: "404 page not found↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: t, …}

Based on "http://localhost/gateway/" logout is found "http://localhost/gateway/auth/logout"

Any ideas on why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been reported here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6652

The fix has been done: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6653 but it's not released yet. You can use the diff to apply the fix in your project.